# Parsing JSON to populate the dhtmlx grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dhtmlx

I get JSON as a response, from an ajax call, the contents of which I then want to be loaded in the grid.

From the JQuery documentation, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/,  for response of type JSON:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
>   object.

So I convert the JavaScript object back to JSON using JSON.stringify:

```
importConfigurationStatusGrid.parse(JSON.stringify(result), "json");
```

But the grid doesn't get populated.

The response I get looks like this:

> {"rows":{"Added to index":["file1", "file2",...."],
>   "Conflicting":["file3", "file4",..."], "Removed":["file5",
>   "file6",...."]}}

I checked the JSON format on https://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__data_formats.html#jsonformat, and I think the difference between the two(the response I get and the format specified) might be the cause.

How can I parse the JSON string using the parse method of dhtmlxGridObject?

```
result = {"rows":{"Added to index":["file1", "file2",...."], "Conflicting":["file3", "file4",..."], "Removed":["file5", "file6",...."]}}
importConfigurationStatusGrid.parse(result, "json");
```

**Edit 1:**

> @ogui: I don't know what your AJAX request looks like, but you can add
>   a dataType property and set it to json so that your result gets
>   automatically parsed as an object for you.

The ajax request does have a `dataType: 'json'` property specified. So there isn't a need to use JSON.parse(). The problem lies in converting the JS object to a valid JSON format that the parse(dhtmlx) method requires.

> @ogui: You could aso use jQuery.getJSON().

Even if I were to use this method, the grid object would have have to parse the same JSON, which it is failing at.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
result = JSON.parse(result);
```

I don't know what your AJAX request looks like, but you can add a `dataType` property and set it to `json` so that your `result` gets automatically parsed as an object for you. This is mentioned in the [jQuery AJAX documentation page you linked](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings). You could aso use [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/).